# Could someone identify what is being said?

Tags: transcription

What does Mélechon say in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtNRZCEfMUI&ab_channel=JEAN-LUCM%C3%89LENCHON) from 1:14:36 to 1:14:40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Mais il faut bien qu'il y ait un débat au PS !*

Mélenchon is making fun of Macron and Hamon, suggesting they were belonging to the same political party, while the actual PS (*Parti socialiste*) primaries debate, won by Hamon, was over and Macron had left the PS since a couple of years and founded his own competing party (*En Marche)*.

It's quite *cocasse* (quirky?) because Mélenchon followed exactly the same path a few years earlier when he founded the *Parti de gauche*.